# Infimum of the set

Tags: real-analysis, supremum-and-infimum

> Prove that  set $S= \{\sin(x)+2\sin(\sqrt{2}x)+3\sin(\sqrt{3} x) \}$ has infimum $-6$.
>   x is positive integer

I have proved that $-6$ is lower bound of this set, but I don't know how to prove that there is no $a>-6$ that is lower bound.

Comment: Please read this before posting: https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference to better format your questions in future. For example, to write $\sin$, you should type `\sin`, not `sin`. Also, use `\cdot` instead of `*` to get the multiplication symbol $\cdot$.

Comment: You are being asked to prove that any $a > -6$ is *not* a lower bound. I.e for any $a > -6$, there is some $s \in S$ so that $s < a$. any $a$ less than the infimum is also a lower bound.

Comment: You should also specify where $x$ lives: $x\in\mathbb{R}$? $x\in\mathbb{R}^+$? $x\in [0,1]$?

Comment: We need to prove that $\forall \epsilon>0$ $\exists x \in \mathbb{R}$ such that
$$-6\le \sin(x)+2\sin(\sqrt{2}x)+3\sin(\sqrt{3} x)\le-6+\epsilon$$ but it doesn't seem trivial in that case.

Comment: Let $x=\frac{3}{2}\pi+2\pi k$ for a $k$, such that both $\sqrt{2}x$ and $\sqrt{3}x$ are near to some $x=\frac{3}{2}\pi+2\pi n$. Use https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dirichlet%27s_approximation_theorem.